# What should I add so that my <select> looks like a select?

Tags: html, css

I am using a buttons library.

I'm applying that style to `<select>` and it is working fine. But it has a look of button instead of a select.

I want to add ▾ to the right, so that it resembles a normal select.

So my assumption is that I should do something in:

```
select.button {
    /* some style here */
}
```

My select is

```
<select class="button is-default">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

And the CSS:

```
.button {
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1px 4px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: inherit;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: none;
    white-space: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: "OpenSansSemiBold",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    line-height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -moz-transition: all .15s ease;
    -o-transition: all .15s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all .15s ease;
    transition: all .15s ease;
}
.button:hover, .button:focus {
    outline: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.button:active, .button.is-active {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.button[disabled], .button.is-disabled {
    opacity: .7;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
    cursor: not-allowed;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.button.is-default {
    border-color: #656d78;
    background-color: #f5f7fa;
    color: #434a54;
}

.button.is-default:hover, .button.is-default:focus {
    border-color: #737c89;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QWMWb/).

Comment: `-webkit-appearance: initial;` ?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you simply spamming css properties without having any idea about what they does..?!!

Comment: @TilwinJoy, That's not my css. I found it at Github

Comment: When completely re-styling elements people will often use a div and then style that. You can also us a plug in such as selectric (http://lcdsantos.github.io/jQuery-Selectric/). If you just want the down arrow, you can use the html down arrow `&#x25BC;` to add the arrow back in.

Comment: yeah, but I  have to manually add it to every `<select>`  @drew_w, do you know how to add that to all select by css?

Comment: @TilwinJoy, the buttons css are from https://github.com/KrisOlszewski/Kanso/

Comment: check out [How to style a <select> dropdown with CSS only without JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript/13968900#13968900)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the line `-webkit-appearance: none;` and you will get the arrow back. At least in  Google Chrome.

Comment: but how to do it for cross browser?

Comment: @AmitJoki you just need to remove that line and by default your select element will look the way you want in all browsers (with the dropdown arrow). The cross-browser problem (if any in this case) is **how to make it like a button** in all browsers, not **how to make it like a normal select** in all browsers.